# How to add a keyboard to a fullscreen layout

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I have a working Kivy app, that uses fullscreen, and consequently I've never used the Window object. I now wish to add a popup keyboard that can be hidden and popped whenever necessary. However, looking into how to do this it appears as if I need a Window object for it to exist in.

So I've added `from kivy.core.window import Window` along with copying the keyboard example on the window documentation on the Kivy site.

However, now my 'fullscreen' app is occupying just part of the screen, and the keyboard is nowhere to be seen? What am I missing?

Added running code:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'borderless', '1')
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1920')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1080')
Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.vkeyboard import VKeyboard
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

Builder.load_file("mykivyfile.kv")


class Widgets(Widget):
    pass


class MyKeyboardListener(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyKeyboardListener, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            # If it exists, this widget is a VKeyboard object which you can use
            # to change the keyboard layout.
            pass
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard have been closed!')
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        print('The key', keycode, 'have been pressed')
        print(' - text is %r' % text)
        print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)

        # Keycode is composed of an integer + a string
        # If we hit escape, release the keyboard
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()

        # Return True to accept the key. Otherwise, it will be used by
        # the system.
        return True



class myApp(App):

    def build(self):
        global w
        w = Widgets()
        return w

    def testy(self):
        runTouchApp(MyKeyboardListener())

    def quitme(self):
        quit()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp().run()
```

mykivyfile.kv :

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<Widgets>:
    Button:
        size: 100,100
        pos: 100,100
        text: 'test'
        on_press: app.testy()

    Button:
        size: 100,100
        pos: 200,100
        text: 'quit'
        on_press: app.quitme()
```

Comment: Do you set the fullscreen config before importing Window?

Comment: Is that a suggestion for a fix, or the problem? :) With the import statement in, I just get a blank screen. I've tried win=Window() to initialize it but it says not callable... I'm not sure what I'm doing TBH! What's the best way to add a window to the code when it previously didn't have one (but still worked ok!)...?

Comment: You always had a Window object. Please provide a runnable example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok I've edited to include all the relevant code.

Comment: The Config.set stuff won't do anything unless you put it before the other imports.

Comment: Yes of course it won't, I've corrected this now, just need to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the keyboard now...?

Comment: Anyone got any clues?